# .NET Google OAuth2 Integration Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, webforms, google-oauth

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to use Google's client to use OAuth2 to do the following:

- Step 1 - Give the user a button to press that launches a prompt asking to authenticate and authorize use of their Calendar (returning the auth code portion of OAuth2's flow) -- I believe this is "Google Sign-In", and since I want offline access, I must specify that somehow -- regardless of whether we use the website or javascript clients.
- Step 2 - Use the auth code returned in step a) to retrieve the refresh and access tokens to be stored and retrieved for use when integrating with the Google Calendar API.
- Step 3 - Use the access token with various Google APIs (Calendar atm) to access services, and refresh when necessary using the refresh token.

The Calendar API itself is out of scope for what I'm asking here, the documentation on that seems unambiguous.  The OAuth2 documentation is what I'm confused by...

Right now I have Step 1 working by using the javascript client, which then gives me the Auth Code to pass to my Server Side WebAPI code.  When I attempt to pass that using WebClient to the token endpoint for Google with grant_type = authorization_code (as described here: http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/), I get a 400 bad request error (in fairness, I am not passing the redirect_url because there is no redirect required at that point, right?)

The bottom line is I have a WebForms app and I'm trying to use Google's client to authenticate a user, get refresh and access tokens for my app and use those to integrate with the API.  The question is how do I do this using Google's own client in a webforms app -- that is not really clear.

TIA

Comment: saying you understand OAuth, and then getting the tokens wrong, isn't a great look :-)  You've got your Refresh Token and Access Token the wrong way round. You say you got an error, but don't say what that error is. Having read the question 3 times, I'm still unclear what it is that you are trying to do that differs from the standard OAuth flow, and why. Try explaining your use case in a bit more detail so we can help.

Comment: I have reworded it.  I think my confusion on the refresh and access tokens came from this article: http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/ Where I saw the first link had a grant_type of authorization_code and the second had a grant_type of refresh token, so without reading the example of the actual object returned (since I can't get mine to return anything) I just missed the part where the initial request returns BOTH tokens... anyway... thanks for responding... I hope my reword makes it more clear -- the last paragraph is pretty straight up what I'm trying to do.

Comment: that's much clearer. A redirect_url is not optional. It's how Google passes control back to your app after the app after it's taken the user through the consent screen (and potentially also the login screen if the user is not yet logged in to Google).